# Run Audit log report programmitically for "Edit User & Permission"

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365apis, spaudit, audit-log-reports

I am able to create audit log report using UI of Sharepoint but everytime I have to
run a custom report. I have to generate this log automatically using Programming. I  have gone through internet and found that **SPAuditQuery** Can be use to obtain Audit Logs But How? Or how can i use **office 365 management api** to generate **"Edit User & Permission"**. In Which type of application we can use it? by the way I am using SharePoint Hosted addin.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSOM/JSOM to generate SharePoint site collection audit logs; the class you referenced is for SharePoint on-prem only.

In general, you shouldn't be using site collection audit logging in SharePoint Online, rather use the Office 365 Security and Compliance center audit logs. Take a look into the [Office 365 Management Activity API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) for a potential API that may fit your requirements.

Comment: In documentation which you have provided, What will be the "REDIRECT URI", btw  i have developed Sharepoint Hosted add-in

Comment: I have to Consume Office 365 Management Activity Api from SharePoint hosted add-in